# What is the proper way to execute JS?

Tags: php, jquery, html

- Is it possible to use JS/JQuery from an external file? If so, what is the best practice?
- What is the best practice to call a *JQuery* function inside a PHP or HTML page?

Here is **file.php**

```
echo "<table..";
echo "some code...";
echo "</table>":
<script type="javascript">
$('table').hide().fadeIn(700);
</script>
```

**or:**

```
echo '<script type="javascript">';
echo '$('#foo').toggle("slow");';
echo '</script>';
```

So, besides a best practice. is any of this possible? I can't seem to make it work from external file or directly.

also from **external.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ $('table').css({ // code here ... }); });
```

Comment: also: `external.js >> $(document).ready(function(){
           $('table').css({
  // code here ... 
});
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly echo jquery (or any html code) directly from PHP

```
echo '<script type="javascript">
        $(\'#foo\').toggle("slow");
        </script>';
```

Your issue in that one was the un-escaped quotes around #foo

I'm not really sure what you meant in the first part of your question, but since you have php I would use this option rather than trying to add jquery into an html file from another javascript file (if that's what you were trying to do)

Comment: As mentioned by Faiz, you don't actually -need- to echo the script from php since you can just close the php tag and reopen it after the script, but you might have a reason for doing it this way (and as he also mentioned we don't know what your circumstances are.)

Answer (score 0):

Both internal and external javascript/jquery code should work.

1. Make sure you jquery script tag was include in you header/body
2. If external, make sure to include the external.js script tag after the jquery script tag
3. Make sure the document was ready first ( $(document).ready() ), and check again the selector either they are exist or not.

For more clean code, no need to echo every single line html code. Just close the php ( ?> ) and write the html as usual.

Please provide as much information as you can so that we know exactly what's the problem was.